# Scaling a div with background image to fit screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image, scale

Most of my pages has a full width banner at the top just under the menu. They are created as a div with a background image from an image sprite file to reduce page load time.
My problem is that the div does not resize when the screen gets smaller, it just cuts the div of. What I would like is that the div is always 100% wide and its height scaling to keep the proportions of the background image (1300px × 300px).

Here' the code and a jsfiddle:

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="banner"></div>
</div>
```

```
.entry-content {
    max-width: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
.banner {
    margin: 0 -20px 0 -20px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url("http://renservice.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/banner-sprites.jpg");
    background-position: 0 -900px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fy2zh4vm/1/

Comment: Do you want the image to resize along with the banner div's width when resized?

Comment: Yes. The image sholud always have the same proportions and be 100% wide.

Comment: Then, you could have used min-width instead of max-width. So that the image always retains it proportion and be 100% wide.

Comment: Alright, but that doesn't really go a very long way towards solving my issue. Notice that the div's height is set to 300px, but I need it to scale dynamically based on screen size, so I need to remove the `height: 300px`, but when I do that, the div collapses.

Comment: @JeppeBech Best way is not to use sprite for your banners. Use single image instead. And use `background-size:cover` property. To resize the div height proportionally, you can use the code written in my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done using a sprite. On the other hand, sprites are most useful if you have lots of small images, whereas you probably have a few big (1300x300) ones, so I suggest to just get rid of the sprite, it won't affect your loading time and you can use `background-size:cover` or `background-size:contain` to have your image react to the size of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a code to resize the div proportionally with width. But don't think sprite image background will solve your problem.

here is a fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/fy2zh4vm/3/

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(e){
$('.banner').height(parseFloat((300/1300)*$(window).width()));
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should try it in the jsfiddle and tell me if that solves the issue? It doesn't.

Comment: For this one you will need to calculate background position too

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `background-size` property you have to set it to either to `cover` or `contain` depends on if you want it to cover the `div` tag or not.

If you want to read more here is the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: Maybe you should split the sprite into multiple images.

Comment: Alright, but then why is everyone telling me to combine images to sprites? Don't they know about responsive design?

Comment: Dont know, but I would use single images.

Comment: @JeppeBech using CSS image sprite is good if you use them for icons and other small artifacts in your site. That way you can reduce server request, hence page load time. But if you are planning to use sprite images as background image which can resize, then better to use separate images.

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in my comment: I suggest you just get rid of the sprite and you can solve your problem with `background-size:cover` or `background-size:contain`.

Just in case you can't do that, I found a solution that works with sprites, but you need javascript for that (i used jQuery, but if you prefer plain JS, that should be quite easy to achieve).

The idea is that you read the `width` of your banner div and adjust its `height` and `background-position` values accordingly.

And here's the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73sryvfw/1/)**

Hope that helps, but again: This is NOT the best solution, this is only the solution if you absolutely have to use sprites!

Comment: The code need to work on resize as well. Edited your fiidle, so that it can work on resize also. check https://jsfiddle.net/73sryvfw/2/. You need to reconsider your background position logic I guess.

Comment: Yeah, adding a resize handler is too simple to mention in a fiddle. That's something everyone should be able to do on their own while the fiddle is intentionally as short as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to replace the sprite with individual images, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible with raw CSS and a little hack. There is a [blog post](http://nicolasgallagher.com/flexible-css-cover-images/) from Nicolas, where he describes how to realize background images with defined proportions.

I made you additionally a [fiddle](http://codepen.io/whotheheck/pen/XdaeJy?editors=1100). 
The percentage in the pseudo element is built by a little calculation: `100 / ( width / height )`.

EDIT: don't know if it works with sprites. But maybe it's nevertheless a help :)